# DB2 SQL: Executing of Multiple Queries / Code

Tags: sql, db2, global

I am trying to run multiple queries, for an example two very simple SELECT statements. Currently I am using Eclipse and the built into SQL editor.

I have found the DSQEC_RUN_MQ global variable but I cannot set / update this to get it to work, I found this [page](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS9UMF_11.2.0/ref/cmn/glv/dsq_glv_cmd_proc.html) but no actual example code.

When I try to set the global variable:

```
SET GLOBAL DSQEC_RUN_MQ=1
```

The log states:

```
SQL Error [42703]: "DSQEC_RUN_MQ" is not valid in the context where it is used.
```

I am simply wanting to run multiple SELECT / INSERT INTO snippets at code, here is an example.

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLES.MYTABLE1;

SELECT * FROM MYTABLES.MYTABLE2;
```

I want to highlight these snippets above and run them both at once.

Comment: please edit your question to clarify it. You can only reference a global variable that is already defined.  You reference a QMF page, why is that?  Are you connecting to a Db2-for-Z/OS mainframe database?

Comment: If you want to have multiple `insert into ...` and or `select ... into` statements grouped together to execute as a single entity, you either need a compound-SQL anonymous-block (inside a Begin... End block),  or instead put the statements into a routine (for example, a stored procedure, or a user defined function) which you when invoke.

Comment: @mao an example of this being done would be very helpful.